# Is there a method for generating a rectangular matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, social-networking, adjacency-matrix, sna

I'm generating networks using the rgnm function from the sna package. E.g.

```
int_mat <- rgnm (1,10,33)
```

Is there a method that I can use to produce a non-square matrix (e.g. 10 x 11 matrix) using this or another function?

Thanks!

Comment: the `matrix` function perhaps?

Comment: `matrix(1:33, nrow = 10, ncol = 11, byrow = T)`

Comment: Ah, but is there a way to fill it in the same way as rgnm does? As an adjacency matrix with 33 1's and the rest as 0's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

```
n_rows <- 10; n_cols <- 11; n_1s <- 33
elements <- rep(0, n_rows* n_cols)
elements[sample(1:length(elements), 33)] <- 1
int_mat <- matrix(elements, nrow=n_rows, ncol=n_cols)
```